# Issues when using interaction term with a lagged variable in R

Tags: r, interaction, lags, panel-data

Today I tried to estimate models using both `plm` and `pgmm` functions in the [plm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/index.html) R package, with an interaction between `X1` and `lag(X2, 1)`. And I notice two issues.

Let $Y=b_1  X_1 + b_2  X_2 + b_3  X_1  X_2 + e$ be our model.

1. When using `plm`, I got different results when I coded the interaction term with `I(X1 * lag(X2, 1))` and when I just saved this multiplication `X1 * lag(X2, 1)` in a different variable of the dataset and then used it in the regression.
2. With `pgmm` it is not even possible to run a formula which contains `I(X1 * lag(X2, 1))`. How can I pass such interaction?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the problem number 2 is easy to solve: instead of using `I(X1 * lag(X2,1))`, one should use `X1:lag(X2,1)`. It works.

The issue number 1 remains, though. And also affects this solution for number 2. It means: results are different with one uses `X1:lag(X2,1)` whithin the formula or uses a new variable previouysly created with `X1*lag(X2,1)`.

Any insights here would be very hepful.

Comment: If you calculate the variable beforehand on your own and put it into the data, make sure the data are alread a pdata.frame so that the `lag` function from package `plm` is executed and not `stats::lag`. `plm::lag` respects the panel structure of the data, `stats::lag` does not know about the panel structure.